# automatically surround tag with another tag

Tags: html, xml, tags, jstl, surround

Does anybody know a way to surround a predefined tag (eg container-tag) automatically with another tag.

eg. you have different container types like article.tag,video.tag,image.tag etc. 
Everytime I call such a container, I want it to automatically be surrounded by another envelope-tag.

`<myc:article/>`

Is this possible? Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: you could use jquery or an html parser but as you seem to have a custom tag you may need to use javascript with a regex

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.. isnt it possible to do define something inside the .tld? Scripting is not an option.

Comment: Sorry, never worked with .tld files so I don't know, I thought you were just talking about a html file and markup

Comment: thx anyway.. I`m looking for any scriptless possibility to achieve an surrounding tag ;) ( automatically called )

Answer (score 0):

One way to go arround this.. is to setup a custom tag (eg called envelope.tag) and commit the name of the inner tag as an attribute. then resolve the name.. and "voila" insert the inner tag (eg inner.tag)

```
<myc:envelope containerType="inner"/>
```

this is it..